# gcc and g++ linker

Tags: gcc

I am not yet at the point of linking, but as soon as my project compiles I will face this issue:

- I have one c.o object file compiled by gcc from pure C code
- I have one d.o object file compiled by g++ with extern"C" for C compatibility of functions that needs to be callable by the c.o
- I have a lot of *.o object files compiled by g++ from pure C++ code that are called by the d.o part

How should I link the whole as a one block shared library? Using gcc or g++?
This library will then be used by Apache2 as a C module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using g++ you can link both types of .o files. Only gcc will fail.

Comment: @ephemient: good point. The issue is indeed missing symbols, so that would be a workaround, too.